# MySql Join with Sum

Tags: sql, mysql, join, outer-join

I have a table called RESULTS with this structure :

resultid,winner,type

And a table called TICKETS with this structure :

resultid,ticketid,bet,sum_won,status

And I want to show each row from table RESULTS and for each result I want to calculate the totalBet and Sum_won using the values from table TICKETS

I tried to make some joins,some sums,but I cant get what I want.

```
SELECT *,COALESCE(SUM(tickets.bet),0) AS totalbets,
      COALESCE(SUM(tickets.sum_won),0) AS totalwins 
FROM `results` NATURAL JOIN `tickets` 
WHERE tickets.status<>0 
GROUP BY resultid
```

Please give me some advice.

I want to display something like this

```
RESULT WINNER TOTALBETS TOTALWINS
1       2        431       222
2       3         0         0
3       1         23        0
4       1         324       111
```

Comment: Could you give some example data and the expected result for this data? I think it would make your question more clear.

Comment: It might also help to post `show create table results \G` and `show create table tickets \G`. What is `raceid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT r.*,
          COALESCE(x.totalbet, 0) AS totalbet,
          COALESCE(x.totalwins, 0) AS totalwins
     FROM RESULTS r
LEFT JOIN (SELECT t.resultid,
                  SUM(t.bet) AS totalbet,
                  SUM(t.sum_won) AS totalwins
             FROM TICKETS t
            WHERE t.status != 0
         GROUP BY t.resultid) x ON x.resultid = r.resultid
```

I don't care for the NATURAL JOIN syntax, preferring to be explicit about how to JOIN/link tables together.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, COALESCE(SUM(tickets.bet),0) AS totalbets,
      COALESCE(SUM(tickets.sum_won),0) AS totalwins 
FROM `results` NATURAL JOIN `tickets` 
WHERE tickets.status<>0 
GROUP BY resultid
```

Try to replace the first `*` with `resultid`. If this helps, then add more columns to `SELECT` and add them to `GROUP BY` at the same time.

Comment: doesnt work ... if I dont have any tickets played for that resultid , then it doesnt return 0